# Android Build tools -- No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

Just yesterday this app worked perfectly fine, yet now it is throwing errors concerning:

[image]

Here are my build files:
*build.gradle (module app):*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19//21
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"//"21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "(app)"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19//21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'
    // Additional
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

How can I configure this to work?

Comment: You need `compileSdkVersion 21`.

Comment: Thanks, I had been on 19 forever given ActionBar. Very simple to transition to ToolBar